# How to set XLM masternode in local or aws server like btc node daemon

Tags: stellar-core, xlm, nodes

docker commands, I'm using for testing purpose in our local machine

docker run --rm -it -p "8000:8000" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --testnet

but

Where to set config file?

How I can create RPC endpoint for

create new address?

create new transaction?

Please correct me If I'm wrong, The steller node is't working like btc or etherem node?

Help would be really appreciative strangers

Thanks **:)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stellar nodes are seperated in two components: stellar-core (p2p processing) and stellar-horizon (client interface, actually I guess the RPC interface you're looking for). Luckily afaik both are contained in the quickstart container and if it's running then you should be able to `curl http://IP:8000` the endpoint. It's not jsonrpc like bitcoind but a similar, open RESTfull http interface and you can find more information as well as lots of SDKs for your prefered language in the [stellar api reference](https://www.stellar.org/developers/reference/).

Nevertheless, for creating an address or creating a transaction (both you can do offline/offchain) you'll need just a SDK - the node is only for requesting account/transaction data or submitting transactions.